# Carriage Returns replacement in IE9

Tags: javascript, regex, xml-parsing, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to display some data in a `<div>` and IE9 is not keeping more than one carriage return.  This works fine in Chrome, but not IE9 (it only adds the `<br/>`) Here's the code:

```
$.get(url,function(xml){
  $("record",xml).each(function(){
    var profile= $("profile",this).text().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,'~').replace(/~~/g,'<\/p>&nbsp;<p>').replace(/~/g,'<br/>');
    profileRpt += profile
  });
});
```

Thought process on this was to normalize, then add `<p>` for double carriage returns and `<br>` for the single returns.

I've also tried the simple replacement,

```
var points= $("points",this).text().replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
```

and again this worked fine in Chrome, but not in IE9.

Does anyone know of a way I can get this to work in IE9?  Thanks!!

**UPDATE**
So it seems that jQuery is the culprit when used in IE, as it collapses the line breaks prior to any replace function.

Can anyone help with using an alternate (non-jQuery) method of retrieving the data from the xml response as I've done above?  One that would preserve the line breaks?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I'm guessing that in IE9 jQuery text() is collapsing contiguous returns.  This means replace() will never be able to fix this.  Is there another way to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function unifyLineFeeds = function(str) {
    return str.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n");
}
```

You can then use this function to output text as HTML following way:

```js
// `text` var contains text with line ununified line feed characters.
text = unifyLineFeeds(text);

var lines = text.split("\n"),
    count = lines.length,
    lastIndex = count - 1;

var container = document.getElementById('someContainerToShowFormattedText');

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i]));

    if (i < lastIndex) {
        container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm getting the same result. IE doesn't give recognize 2 carriage returns. Still only gives me a single `<br>`

Comment: This clearly would work if the (text) part was passed untouched.  Unfortunately, in my code I'm extracting this text from an xml response using jQuery which, in IE, is collapsing the line breaks before even getting to this point.  Do you know how I can retrieve the data from the xml response using a method other than jQuery?

Comment: @kwmcnutt Consider using [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) which is typically easier to use and more predictable than XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
var points = $("points", this).text().replace(/\r+/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

Comment: also something, what does this code do ? Simple code is not an proper answer.

Comment: @Lucifer - I believe it is obvious :: Removes all `\r` and then replaces each `\n` with `<br>`

Comment: well i just saw your answer in low-quality post, so for review, i suggest you to write something with the code :)

Comment: Same result.  IE doesn't give recognize 2 carriage returns.  Still only gives me a single `<br>`

Comment: @kwmcnutt - What version of IE you use?

Comment: What you get using `.text().replace(/[^\S ]/g, '<br>');`? *(notice space behind \S)*.

Comment: @kwmcnutt - Strange! What if you use `innerHTML()` instead of `text()`..?

Comment: Could I use a conditional where if its IE use `<p>` else use `<br>`?

Comment: @kwmcnutt - Yes, but that is not what I like... Did you try to use `innerHTML`? Or did you try to play with replacement, such as `&nbsp;<br>` instead of `<br>`?

Comment: Have not tried innerHTML as pulling the data from xml and inserting into a `<div>`.  I've tried a few different combos, but it seems that in IE9 jQuery text() is collapsing contiguous returns. This means replace() will never be able to fix this. I

Comment: @kwmcnutt - That's why try `innerHTML`, as it is pure JavaScript function, not jQuery..

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being a noob, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the data from an xml response using innerHTML.  Any chance you could show me quick and dirty example?

Comment: @kwmcnutt - Not sure, but try just replace `.text()` with `.innerHTML()` in your code

Comment: That's part of the $() jQuery function which is causing the issue.  I'll update the question and see if someone can help out.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @kwmcnutt - I know it is part of jQuery, but you can mix jQuery with pure JavaScript. Also `replace` is pure JavaScript function, so you already mix them... Did you actually try that? `$("profile",this).innerHTML().replace...`

Comment: Good point! :)  To that end, I did try it and it gives me a `Object [object Object] has no method 'innerHTML'` console error.

Comment: @kwmcnutt - Maybe you will need to modify value of `xml` parameter before `each` execution...